# Avoiding Nan computation

Tags: numpy, nan

Can someone help me with this? I'm trying to avoid nan value in my resulting List. because if p gets too close to zero, it is generating nans in my new list.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import log 


def Compute(ListA):
    NewListA = []
    p = random.random()
    for item in ListA:
        u=np.exp(-(float(item)/500)**1.2)
        y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
        while y == nan:
            continue
        else:
            y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
            NewListA.append(y)
    return NewListA

ListA = [2.00345, 0.004, 3.0876, 6.00034, 8.0777, 9.444, 0.0004, 11.000678]
print (Compute(ListA))
```

Comment: I fixed the code formatting in your question, next time please use the live preview before posting. I'm not sure how you get `nan`s. Minor note: you have some unnecessary things in your code: either import `uniform` and call it `uniform`, or import `random` and use `random.uniform`. And there's a `np.random.uniform` which might work for you, then you don't need to import anything other than numpy.

Comment: Your newest edit broke the formatting that I had fixed. Please correct it yourself this time by [edit]ing.

Comment: Thanks Andras Deak

Comment: Andras, this List is varying. In fact, I want to compute a left truncated inverse weibull random variable. As you can see, if the values inside the log gets too close to zero or to one, I'm getting NaNs for some Entry Lists.

Comment: Don't you actually want to generate a new random number for each element in the list, and keep generating new random numbers until you don't have nans?

Comment: Exactly Andreas!... yes, you made it clear.. normaly I would use a  (Do,                   Generate Value,      Loop While Value = NaN) in other languages. But I seem not to get python to do it

Comment: You're missing a loop for generating a new random number for each list element. You need `for` over your list -> `while` to generate a random number, `break` in case you get a good random number. Another option is to constrain your uniform numbers to avoid the neighbourhood of 0, and in this case you can generate all the numbers at once using `np.random.uniform(minval,maxval,len(ListA))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` instead of `while`; and `isnan` instead of `==nan`.

```
    if np.isnan(y):   #while y == nan:
        continue
    NewListA.append(y)   # don't need to repeat y calc?
```

You want to skip this `item` not some new iteration on `y`.  When I used your syntax I got stuck in an infinite loop that I had to kill.

```
In [324]: for item in range(10):
     ...:     while item==5:
     ...:         continue
     ...:     else:
     ...:         print(item)
     ...:         
0
1
2
3
4
<infinite loop>
```

Your code doesn't get stuck because `y==nan` is always `False`.

Corrected iteration:

```
In [1]: alist=[]
In [2]: for item in range(10):
   ...:     if item==5:
   ...:         continue
   ...:     else:
   ...:         alist.append(item)

In [4]: alist
Out[4]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And alternative to the `continue` block.

```
for item ...
    y = ....
    if not np.isnan(y):
       newList.append(y)
```

Comment: @hpaulj actually, I think it makes equal sense to keep the while loop. Because you want to retry computing y until it passes muster, it has a random component so this isn't necessarily an infinte loop. You could soften your "use if instead of while".

Comment: But you have make some sort of change within `while`, such as calculating new `p`.  It's the bare `while ... continue` that is dangerous and meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the other working solution. It produces output of predictable length (equal to the input's)

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import log 


def Compute(ListA):
    NewListA = []
    for item in ListA:
        u=np.exp(-(float(item)/500)**1.2)
        p = random.random()
        y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
        while np.isnan(y):
            p = random.random()
            y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
        NewListA.append(y)
    return NewListA

ListA = [2.00345, 0.004, 3.0876, 6.00034, 8.0777, 9.444, 0.0004, 11.000678]
print (Compute(ListA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer to the problem. I guess it is more appropriate to keep the while loop, as Paul stated. But both codes work . . . Thank you guys.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import log 

def Compute2(ListA):
    NewListB = []
    p = random.random()   
    for item in ListA:
        u=np.exp(-(float(item)/500)**1.2)
        y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
        while np.isnan(y):   
            continue      
        else:
            y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/1.2))
            NewListB.append(y)                      
    return NewListB

ListB = [2.00345, 0.004, 3.0876, 6.00034, 8.0777, 9.444, 0.0004, 11.000678]
print (Compute2(ListB))
```

Answer (score -1):

In a python shell try the following

```
np.nan == np.nan
```

Look at the result and then think about what this means for your `while` loop.

Hint: there is an [isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) function for a reason.

The other of your troubles are not `nan` related. Actually, the version you postetd isn't that far off.
You want your `Compute` function to compute a new value for each value in your original list. The new value has a random component but also depends by some formula on the old value.

To implement that you have correctly set up a function that takes the old list as an argument. You correctly initalise the new list at the beginning of the function and you correctly start a loop over the old list.

Now comes the first problem: You need a new random number for each element you're looping over. Loops are local they only apply to what's *inside*. Inside in python means in in the indented block following the line with the `for` statement. Therefore:

```
- where has the line marked (1) to be placed?
```

Because of your nan problem you have to check every new value before you can accept it and as long as it is nan you have to repeat the computation of the new value. For this you have set up a while loop. This should be repeated as long as the new value is nan. But as we have discussed you cannot compare with nan. nan stands for "not a number". Now two things that are both not a number needn't be equal. Therefore comparing nan with nan or anything  will never return True. To still be able to check for nan there is a dedicated function called isnan. You must use it here. Thus

```
- how must the line marked (2) be modified?
```

The continue statement is nonsense. You haven't set up the while loop just to hop out at the first corner. The purpose of the loop is to give a fresh try at computing your new value, thus you must draw a new random number and do the calculation again. Hence

```
- which two lines do you have to copy and use to replace the bogus continue statement marked (3)?
```

The else clause is not needed, remove it. You are now at the end of the for loop, the inner while loop has terminated. Remember that that happens if and only if the loop condition is False.

```
- what does that mean for `y`? Can it still be `nan` at this point?
```

Based on the last answer only one of the two next actions makes sense: a) compute a new `y`, b) accept the current `y` and store it in the output list, therefore

```
- which of the lines (4, 5) do you need to keep, which do you need to delete?
```

Don't forget to unindent that line by one level; otherwise the computer will think it belongs to the while loop.

Congratulations, your program should run now.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import log 


def Compute(ListA):
    NewListA = []
    p = random.random()  # (1)
    for item in ListA:
        u=np.exp(-(float(item)/500)**1.2)
        y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/500))
        while y == nan:  # (2)
            continue     # (3)
        else:
            y=500*((np.log(1/(u*(1-p))))**(1/500))  # (4)
            NewListA.append(y)                      # (5)
    return NewListA

ListA = [2.00345, 0.004, 3.0876, 6.00034, 8.0777, 9.444, 0.0004, 11.000678]
print (Compute(ListA))
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That better? I`m trying to convey something important in a way that makes it stick. While in a very technical way this is not an answer, it makes it very easy to find it.

Comment: Nobody who needs to read your message will stumble upon this question (assuming that the question will even be here in two weeks). If you want to instruct OP, you can do that in a comment. Whether an answer is an answer is entirely a technical question. But your answer is not an answer in any meaningful way, since OP has much more basic problems than testing nans by value. This subtlety (however important!) is three steps down that road.

Comment: Hello Paul, It verifies to False. That I know since I have seen similar comments from people. It is just that I have just started coding in python. That is why you might find my question stupid lol .. sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @EricEnkele but that means for your test that it always will evaluate to False, so your while loop will never be entered. As @Andreas Deak so helpfully points out there are other problems with that loop, but these seem to be more syntax related. The thing that you want to repeat goes _inside_ the while loop. This is muddied in your case because you need it also where you already have it before the loop. (To have `y` defined for the first loop condition) Bit ugly, but happens often in this situation.

Comment: @EricEnkele who is supposed to read that? Can't you at least temporarily put in your question? What I do see is that you still directly compare y to nan. I thought we had reached a consensus on that. Also you seem to stack the same for loop on top of itself. Let me tell you that's not often a good idea.

Comment: @Paul Panzer haha Oh Lord!!! I made a mistake lol ... I am still reading. some people have suggested masking the nan results etc. Could you -if possible at all, show me how I can do this Loop correctly (as an answer, not as a response here?).

Comment: @EricEnkele I haven't fixed it for you but I've given you quite detailed instructions on how to fix it yourself. And on top of that you can peek at hpaulj's answer for additional hints. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Hello Paul. You were right about the while Loop it should be kept .. Thank you to you both

Comment: Your comments were very useful .. many thanks Guys. especially the long lecture by Paul .. thanks Andreas too l

Comment: @Paul Panzer. The code works fine outside but when I am trying to incorporate it inside my main sode it says: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. do you know why?

Comment: I don't know by heart which dtypes make isnan choke. strings do but I don't think a string would make it that far. the simplest thing you can try is inserting a print statement before the line that triggers the error. just slip a `print(item, type(item), y, type(y))` in there and try again

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer